# Find the arc length of the graph of the given equation from $P$ to $ Q$ or on the specified interval.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$y=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4x}$ from $1$ to $3$

I know that the arc length equation is the $\sqrt{1+f'(x)}$ but for some reason I am having problems with this question. I got that the derivative was $\dfrac{1}{4} + x^2$. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your derivative is not correct. $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[\frac1x\right] \neq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $1+(f'(x))^2 = \left(x^2 + \dfrac{1}{4x^2}\right)^2$

Comment: I got the integral as x^3/3- 1/48x^3 +x.... is that right?

Comment: So now i am stuck on the integration of the square root of (x^4+1/16x^4+3/2)

Comment: See my hint for the details. Usually the square root of $1+f'^2$ is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the arc length of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is given by $$\int_a^b\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2}\space dx$$ it makes sense that if you are expected to solve an arc length problem, the nasty looking $\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2}$ quantity has to simplify to something that is integrable. It is often the case that $1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2$ can be rewritten in terms of a function $h(x)$ such that $1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2 = h(x)^2$, and hence $\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} = h(x)$ where $h(x)$ can be integrated. That is true of this problem as well. So, given $y(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^{-1}}{4}$ then $f'(x) = x^2-\frac{x^{-2}}{4}$, and then $$\begin{align}1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2 = 1+\left(x^2-\frac{x^{-2}}{4}\right)^2 \\ = 1+x^4-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^{-4}}{16} \\ = x^4+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^{-4}}{16} \\ = \left(x^2+\frac{x^{-2}}{4}\right)^2  \end{align}$$ Can you take it from here?